# iam new in django , static files are not loading on browser only images are loading css, and js are not loading

Tags: python, django

but the same project is perfectly working on my laptop

this is my setting(debug is true)

```
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'demo/static')),
  )
 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')
```

This is Url

```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from django.urls import path, include

   urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('demo/', include('demo.urls')),

    ]
```

This is my html page of template

```
   {% load static %}
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 
   "images/icons/favicon.ico" %}">

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 
"vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" >

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 
"vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" %}" >

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/util.css" %}" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/main.css" %}" >

</head>
<body>

<div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url({% static 
'images/siva2.jpg' %});">
        <div class="wrap-login100 p-t-30 p-b-50">
            <span class="login100-form-title p-b-41">
    ropDownSelect1"></div>
<script src="{% static "vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js" %}" > 
<script src="{% static "js/main.js"  %}" ></script>
```

in terminal i can see only getting images there is not any result of  getting css files and others

Here is my log on Terminal

[04/Feb/2020 12:53:24] "GET /demo/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4656
   [04/Feb/2020 12:53:24] "GET /static/images/icons/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 
   32038
   [04/Feb/2020 12:53:30] "GET /demo/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4656
   [04/Feb/2020 12:53:30] "GET /static/images/icons/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 
   32038
   [04/Feb/2020 12:53:30] "GET /demo/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4656
   [04/Feb/2020 12:53:31] "GET /static/images/icons/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 
   32038
    [04/Feb/2020 12:53:31] "GET /demo/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4656
   [04/Feb/2020 12:53:31] "GET /static/images/icons/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 
    32038
    [04/Feb/2020 12:53:31] "GET /demo/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4656
    [04/Feb/2020 12:53:31] "GET /static/images/icons/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 
    32038
    [04/Feb/2020 12:53:31] "GET /demo/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4656
     [04/Feb/2020 12:53:31] "GET /static/images/icons/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 
    32038
    [04/Feb/2020 12:53:31] "GET /demo/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4656
    [04/Feb/2020 12:53:31] "GET /static/images/icons/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 
    32038
above is my log on terminal i cant see getting css on terminl

Comment: Try running `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: wt did i have to do after running collect static

Comment: `runserver` and see if it fixed the issue

Comment: i tried but no change

Answer (score 0):

you have to include the following line in your main url pattern to [serve static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/) during development.

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: follow the docs, try with STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

Comment: also add {% load static %} tag on top of the template

Comment: i tried , but no change but the background image in the browser is not the image in static files what is the issue

Comment: post your template also

Comment: image issue solved dear i just rename the image but still the css js is not loading

Answer (score 0):

problem solved the system i was used was prevoisly used by php development ,so  i just reset system

Answer (score 0):

Though late but it is worth checking. Edge has the definitive problem of keeping old websites dt for a long time in its cache. So clear the browser cache if your case is that your website is loading properly in a different browser, then definitely the cache is the problem. Remove all browsing data.